Salesforce - Duplicate value found error while trying to delete a record
We are getting an error while trying to delete a record in an Apex class. I have gone through some research for this error (listed below). However, these examples talk about this error while doing an insert/upsert. I am yet to find information about this error while doing a delete.
We have even tried deleting one record at a time and still get this error for some of the records (not all records as we are able to delete other records).
Please note that we are able to delete other records of this object. So, access is not an issue. However, we get this error for some of the records.
There is only one field on the object that is marked as unique and the value in this field for the record is blank. So, this is not an issue either.
Here is what I have already found:
Here is the error we are getting:
"Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id [recordId here]; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found:  duplicates value on record with id: : []"
Appreciate any help you can provide with this issue as I have tried everything that I can think about and have not been able to find the root cause of this error.

run the operation with debug log enabled (have dev console open or setup -> debug logs). Should provide you with hint what's happening, is there a before delete trigger for example or flow trying to run some side effects.

There is no before or after delete trigger. Also, the debug logs don't provide any more detail that what I have posted in my original post.

How do you delete, from UI or code? 1 record at a time or bulk? Is it plain delete or account merge operation for example? If you get this from UI the there must be some code running. Is this a detail in some weird master detail and you have rollup summaries - is there any uniqueness based in them? Like some crazy "each orde must have different count of order lines"

@eyescream Here are the answers to your question:

We are deleting Contact records.
The delete is from an Apex class.
It is a plain delete.
It is a single delete.


looks like there is a trigger in delete and trigger another insert method to insert records. When you are deleting the record you are performing another operation that inserts the record with the same / duplicate record.

@KishorBikramOli There is no delete trigger on the Contact object.

@Imtiyaz Do you have any records in recycle bin with same external id field?

I've had the same problem trying to delete Contacts.  It looks like this is caused by duplicate EmailMessageRelation records (which only become duplicate when the Contact Id is removed from the RelationId field)
More info on the Salesforce Known Issue:  https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAwaZAAS/duplicate-value-found-unknown-duplicates-value-on-record-with-id-unknown-when-attempting-to-delete-a-record-with-duplicate-emailmessagerelatio
